# Access dynamically created UserControl's Public Declare - WinForms

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

### Logic

There is Form1 with a FlowLayoutPanel 'flowItems' to be populated by UserControl 'UCItem'. For populating flowItems, an array is used. For-Loop loopes over the array and creates a new UCItem, gives it a tag name with number and adds it to flowItem. All this part works.

### Issue

I want to change the public declared boolean variable 'isChecked' each time the newly created UCItem is clicked. For achieving this, I've added an event handler (UCItem.Click) which gets and sets the property.

How ever, I'm unable to access the public boolean variable in UCItem.

### Code: UC_Item.vb

```
Public isChecked As Boolean = False

Private Sub toggle_color()
    If Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24) Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
        Me.txtName.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
        Me.txtName.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Me.BackgroundImage = Nothing
        isChecked = True
    Else
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24)
        Me.txtName.BackColor = Color.Black
        Me.txtName.ForeColor = Color.White
        Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "/res/UCItem_Wallpaper.png")
        isChecked = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UC_Item_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
    toggle_color()
End Sub

Private Sub TxtName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtName.Click
    toggle_color()
End Sub
```

### Code: Form1.vb

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim UCItem As UC_Item

    flowItems.SuspendLayout()
    For i As Integer = 0 To items.Count - 1
        UCItem = New UC_Item
        UCItem.Tag = "UCItem" & i
        UCItem.txtName.Text = items(i).ToString
        flowItems.Controls.Add(UCItem)
        UCItem.Show() : UCItem.Visible = True
        AddHandler(UCItem.Click), AddressOf UCItem_Click
    Next
    flowItems.ResumeLayout()

End Sub

Private Sub UCItem_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' -- not working part --
    ' If sender.isChecked = True Then
    '        sender.isChecked = False
    '  else
    '        sender.isChecked = True
End Sub
```

### Tried

I've tried passing 'UCItem As sender.Tag' but this doesn't work too. I can't access the .Tag and .Name property of sender in the click event.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try this: change the `Public isChecked As Boolean = False` to be a `Public Property`, and try `CType(sender, UCItem).isChecked = `

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. Upvoted

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!